# If last character of string in list is "-" move it to beginning of string

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have split a string to produce the following:

```
Transaction = ['03/29/18', '16,545,275.32-', '8,309,931.13-', '24,855,206.45-', '2.18', '1,505.11']
```

How can I check each string in the list to identify if it ends with '-' and if it does move it to the front of the string? Output should resemble:

```
Transaction = ['03/29/18', '-16,545,275.32', '-8,309,931.13', '-24,855,206.45', '2.18', '1,505.11']
```

Comment: `endswith`, `[:-1]`, .... Something like: `['-' + t[:-1] if t.endswith('-') else t for t in Transaction]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one liner with list comprehension:

```
>>> Transaction = ['03/29/18', '16,545,275.32-', '8,309,931.13-', '24,855,206.45-', '2.18', '1,505.11']

>>> ['-' + i[:-1] if i[-1] is '-' else i for i in Transaction]
['03/29/18', '-16,545,275.32', '-8,309,931.13', '-24,855,206.45', '2.18', '1,505.11']
```

Explanation:

Here `i` is iterator which iterating each element in list `Transaction`

`i[-1]` - get last character of string (works for non empty string)

`i[:-1]` - slice string from starting element upto last character (excludes last characters)

python evaluates expression `i[-1] is '-'` faster compare to `i.endswith('-')`

```
In [2]: %timeit ['-' + i[:-1] if i[-1] is '-' else i for i in Transaction]
950 ns ± 7.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit ['-' + i[:-1] if i.endswith('-') else i for i in Transaction]
1.52 µs ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit ['-' + i[:-1] if i[-1] == '-' else i for i in Transaction]
1.1 µs ± 4.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Excellent, this worked exactly as I needed it to. Appreciate the help.